# How to loop this Python program

Tags: python

How can I loop this code so that it asks the user to search for another file if the file has not been found?

```
import os, sys
from stat import *
from os.path import join

lookfor = input("\nPlease enter file name you want to search? \n")
def search(directory):
      for files in os.listdir(directory):
            fileItem = os.path.join(directory, files)
            fileItemStatInfo = os.stat(fileItem)
            if S_ISDIR(fileItemStatInfo.st_mode):
                  search(fileItem)
            elif S_ISREG(fileItemStatInfo.st_mode):
                  print("Searching", fileItem)
                  if lookfor in files:
                        print("\nThe File Has Been Found: %s" % join(directory, lookfor))
                        break
```

Comment: Question is too localized. Can't see it being of general use.

Comment: @fgb: Actually, this general problem—"How do I loop around input and testing the input?"—is very general, and comes up all the time. The other stuff (everything inside the `search` function) is just a red herring, except for the fact that it has to return something. So really, this is likely a dup. But I can't find a good question to link it to.

Comment: @abarnert: Yeah, I guess the gist of the issue is that the question is poorly posed. We should find the dupe, if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make `search` return success or failure:

```
def search(directory):
      for files in os.listdir(directory):
            fileItem = os.path.join(directory, files)
            fileItemStatInfo = os.stat(fileItem)
            if S_ISDIR(fileItemStatInfo.st_mode):
                  return search(fileItem)
            elif S_ISREG(fileItemStatInfo.st_mode):
                  print("Searching", fileItem)
                  if lookfor in files:
                        print("\nThe File Has Been Found: %s" % join(directory, lookfor))
                        return True
```

(Note that if we fall off the end of the `for` loop, we'll fall off the end of the function, which means we return `None`. Therefore, the function an only return `True`, with is truthy, or `None`, which is not.)

Now, you just loop until it returns something true:

```
while True:
    lookfor=input("\nPlease enter file name you want to search? \n")
    if search(lookfor):
        break
    print('Could not find that file, sorry. Try again.')
```

---

All that said, I don't think `search` does what you want it to—and you can simplify it tremendously, too.

First, I'm not sure whether you're trying to use `lookfor` as a global variable, or as a closure within the `search` function… but either way, you probably shouldn't be doing that. Pass it as an argument.

Also, having a variable named `files` that holds each filename, instead of a collection of them, is very confusing.

If you want to walk a directory tree recursively, use `os.walk` instead of trying to implement it yourself.

And you should probably be printing out the found filename, not the looked-for fragment.

Putting that together:

```
def search(lookfor, directory):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            if lookfor in filename:
                print("\nThe File Has Been Found: %s" % join(dirpath, filename))
                return True
```

---

Of course in most real-life code, you'll probably want to *return* the pathname, so the rest of your code can use it (e.g., to open the file), instead of just printing it out:

```
def search(lookfor, directory):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            if lookfor in filename:
                return join(dirpath, filename)

while True:
    lookfor=input("\nPlease enter file name you want to search? \n")
    path = search(lookfor)
    if path:
        break
    print('Could not find that file, sorry. Try again.')

with open(path) as f:
    pass # now we can actually use the file we searched so hard for
```